# Comments Box realtime updates

Tags: api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

It seems the Comments Box fetches new comments (by other people) only on component reload. Does anyone know any other ways to make the box to fetch updates than reload? I would rather avoid the reload as it naturally clears the input box in case the visitor is in the midst of writing a comment.

The only option I can currently think of is to write my own comment box UI component (read comments via API, render, trigger updates via push from my own service), but doing that sounds rather dumb. (At least when the sole purpose would be to get the damn thing to update itself.)

Comment: +1 you answered your own question :D Currently there isnt a realtime update option for social plugins

Answer (score 0):

That would be a great suggestion to send to facebook since there is no such option to turn on (or off) real-time updates.  Your option you said is dumb, is not really dumb at all. It is the solution to your requirements.

Comment: I posted this to FB bug tracking (as I couldn't find a place for tracking features), https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/244972682242795

It's just that this one little app I'm coding (where I need real-time comments) needs development as well, and I could better focus on it if this “small enhancement” of this one component was readily provided.. :)

Comment: Wow, that was quick!  Also Facebook's response was quick too on the bug report  :O

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution but you can call this function :

FB.XFBML.parse();

every X seconds